# Checking if EditText is empty via listener

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I know there are several answers for this, but none seem to address my problem:

I have the following code:

```
   myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

     }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Log.i("Ram = ", myEditTExt.getText().toString());
            Log.i("Ram = ", s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Log.i("Ram = ", myEditTExt.getText().toString());
            Log.i("Ram = ", s.toString());

        }
    });
```

Neither onTextChanged or afterTextChanged shows is called when the Text is made completely empty. Example Run - this is the same case whether I called the method onTextChanged or afterTextChanged.

The TextBox starts with the value of 25.0 and I click on it and delete it one character at a time and this is the output on the log

Note that I only put 1 statement - I've written all four statements for clarity on what I've tried, but any of the 4 only give me the below output:

```
04-11 17:24:37.661 11221-11221/zooter.com.cal I/Ram =: 25.
04-11 17:24:39.493 11221-11221/zooter.com.cal I/Ram =: 25
04-11 17:24:41.198 11221-11221/zooter.com.cal I/Ram =: 2
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: what you want only you wants to check weather editText is empty ?

Comment: if(myEditTExt.getText().toString().length()==0){ //Do Stuff} This will do the trick for you

Comment: @JhamanDas - don't understand your question

Comment: @RakshitNawani - why is the log statement not being called and in which Listener should I put the If condition?

Comment: First make different tags for your Log.d and use  "onTextChanged" listener

Comment: @zooter : Did that work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                Log.i("Ram = ", "Empty");
                Log.i("Ram = ", "");
            }

            Log.i("Ram = ", myEditText.getText().toString());
            Log.i("Ram = ", s.toString());
        }
```

android.util.Log doesn't work if the log message is empty. (see second log call inside if condition doesn't work).
However I think you're not using the tag correctly. I suggest doing the following:

```
private static final String TAG = "RAM";
...
    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Ram: " + s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Ram: " + s.toString());

        }
    });
```

Or set TAG to the Activity name (actually TAG is only useful for filtering logcat)

Comment: Everybody, thanks for the help, but this is the most accurate answer. 
i.e. Log.i("Ram = ", "") // This will not work....
android.util.Log doesn't work if the log message is empty. Nothing to do with whether I use Log.i or Log.d or change the log tags

Answer (score 2):

try this with your myEditText

```
    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                System.out.println(">>>>>" + s.toString().length());

                 if(s.toString().length()==0){
                       //DO Stuff Here
                  }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Output is Below

> > I/System.out﹕ >>>>>1
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>2
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>3
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>4
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>5
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>6
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>7
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>8
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>9
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>10
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>11
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>10
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>9
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>8
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>7
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>6
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>5
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>4
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>3
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>2
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>1
>
> I/System.out﹕ >>>>>0

Comment: helpful but not an explanation of why it's not working

Answer (score 2):

You should put your if condition in afterTextChanged function.Like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Log.d("", "afterTextChanged —>"+s.getText().toString());
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s.getText().toString()){
        //here to do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried ur code on my system , it works

- you don't need both

  ```
          Log.i("Ram = ", myEditTExt.getText().toString());
          Log.i("Ram = ", s.toString());
  ```

Either 1 will do

And as @Rakshit Nawani suggested use different tags .. should work

Answer (score 0):

check condition onTextChanged

```
edit_cellphone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onTextChanged: "+"empty");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });
```

that's all... enjoy your coding...